# CitrusGraphics Framework not found in PayUMoney IOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, github, payumoney

Iam trying to integrate PayUMoney Payment gateway in swift. When installing pod 'PayUmoney_PnP', it asks for username and password. I checked the sdk file, CitrusGaphics framework is not there.
It's not there in the git too -- https://github.com/citruspay/citruspay-ios-sdk/tree/f69a3c0a6335b78bfade7a6d641b2459e0c40a4e

Comment: Please add code for the same. Without code its pretty hard to resolve and suggest some solution.

Comment: what code? The problem is in installing pod. Coding not started. There is no framework (CitrusGraphics) file in the sdk

Comment: May be i was not clear. Your podfile changes.

Comment: i am facing the same issue while installing pod it showing an error  CitrusGraphics is not found , then i try to clone the repository in this case the  CitrusGraphics folder is showing empty

Answer (score 0):

i have faced the same issue and by contacting the PayuMoney got this response

> We are making deployment in code. Pods will be available on Friday.
>
> Kindly hold integration till that time. Sorry for the inconvenience.
>
> Regards, Disha Mukherjee
>
> Please note that response handling is an important part of the
>   integration. It is absolutely mandatory that the hash (or checksum) is
>   computed again after you receive the response from PayU and compare it
>   with PayU response parameters. This will protect you from any
>   tampering by the user and help in ensuring safe and secure transaction
>   experience. Our integration engineer will advise and assist you with
>   the same. However, if your web or mobile application goes live with
>   PayU as a payment provider but without reverse hash comparison
>   mechanism in the response handling, PayU will not be liable for any
>   loss incurred as a result of this.